# Error when trying to import SQL dumps into MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am currently trying to import several SQL dumps into MySQL Workbench, but I am receiving the following error:

> ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 10: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the
>   value of 'POSTGRESQL'
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

The files I am trying to import have been downloaded from https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/2013-snapshot

Do you have any idea what might be causing this? My goal is to convert these dumps into CSV files that I can later import to Python, so if there is another workaround for this problem that would be very helpful.

Comment: Where is `POSTGRESQL` coming from? Is that in the cruchbase data or are you connecting to a psql server?

Comment: It sounds like the dumps were made from a different RDBMS (PostGres), so you shouldn't expect compatibility with MySQL.

Comment: If I open the dumps in WordPad it says "MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)".

There is also a line that says "SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,POSTGRESQL' */;"
Could this be what's causing the error?

Comment: Here are the docs for MySQL 5.5 sql_mode var. I see no ref to POSTGRESQL being a valid value. You might need to reach out to crunchbase. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode

Comment: Or just try deleting the ",POSTGRESQL" and see if workbench imports it :shrug: